# VIM : syntax highlighting gone after clicking another file

Tags: vim

I have a problem with syntax highlighting in gvim.
i have the following command in my vimrc file:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.v,*.vs,*.va set syntax=verilog
```

However if i'm in gvim reading a file - "a.txt" and i also have "b.txt" open on split, when i click on b and then return to a , the syntax highlighting is gone after the click.
someone tried to explain to me that the autocmd not always running.
any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`BufRead`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#BufRead) option only applies when reading a file into a *new* buffer, so it makes sense that simply switching between splits won't trigger the auto command. The file has already been read into the buffer; it's not read again unless you close and reopen it.

You want the option [`BufEnter`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#BufEnter), as it triggers on *entering* a buffer. Your new command should then look like:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead,BufEnter *.v,*.vs,*.va set syntax=verilog
```

As a side note, it's probably better to use `filetype` instead of `syntax`, as `syntax` won't affect indentation rules, if there are any. Or even better, use a plugin to get everything set up automagically without needing explicit autocommands in your `.vimrc`. Just from a quick Google, [this plugin](https://github.com/vhda/verilog_systemverilog.vim) pops up a bunch.